# Testing multiflavor project in android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit

I have a multiflavor project in android studio and I want to create unit tests for all flavors. As soon as the flavors share same code, it is reasonable to create a folder with "generic" tests - test common for all flavors and a folder  for each flavor contaning individual tests for the flavor.
I have read the instructions under 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing1, but it does not explain in detail if this is possible and how to apply it.

If I create under `src` a folder `AndroidTest` and a folder `AndroidTestFlavor1`, then only one of them is recognized as test folder and in the other does not find `junit`. My questions are therefore:

- Can I create the folders `AndroidTest`, `AndroidTestFlavor1`, `AndroidTestFlavor2`, so as the first one to contain the common test and the others the test of flavors? In which structure should I create them?
- How can I run the tests for each flavor and how the common tests? 
  Is it possible to run both the common tests and the specific flavor tests when executing test for a flavor?
  Even though I created the folder `AndroidTestFlavor1`, the only task which runs on the command window for testing is still: `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`
  and it executes though the tests of `AndroidTestFlavor1`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing1).

> **Q#1** - Can I create the folders AndroidTest, AndroidTestFlavor1,
>   AndroidTestFlavor2, so as the first one to contain the common test and
>   the others the test of flavors? In which structure should I create
>   them?

**Yes you can.** As per documentation this is how you do it.

> Testing multi-flavors project is very similar to simpler projects.
>
> The androidTest sourceset is used for common tests across all flavors,
>   while each flavor can also have its own tests.
>
> As mentioned above, sourceSets to test each flavor are created:
>   android.sourceSets.androidTestFlavor1 Location src/androidTestFlavor1/
>   android.sourceSets.androidTestFlavor2 Location src/androidTestFlavor2/

...

> ```
> Similarly, those can have their own dependencies:
> dependencies {
>     androidTestFlavor1Compile "..."
> }
> ```

....

> **Q#2** - How can I run the tests for each flavor and how the common tests? Even
>   though I created the folder AndroidTestFlavor1, the only task which
>   runs on the command window for testing is still: ./gradlew
>   connectedAndroidTest and it executes though the tests of
>   AndroidTestFlavor1.

...

> ```
> Each flavor has its own task to run tests: androidTest<VariantName>. For instance:
> androidTestFlavor1Debug
> androidTestFlavor2Debug
> Similarly, test APK building tasks and install/uninstall tasks are per variant:
> assembleFlavor1Test
> installFlavor1Debug
> installFlavor1Test
> uninstallFlavor1Debug
> ...
> ```

Comment: I have read the instructions. When I run on the command line: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTestFlavor1Debug, I receive the error message Task 'connectedAndroidTestFlavor1Debug' not found in project. Should I define the task anywhere?